# Angularjs - Loading form in popup

Tags: developer, angular

I've seen some old questions about this with limited response so I'm hoping I get better responses with this question.
I have an angular form that grabs a bunch of baseline information, and has a button on the bottom that says Add Component.  This is a many to one relationship - so they can have many components for this one form.
I want this secondary form to use crm-popup, to make it clean and consistent, however, I can't seem to load an Angularjs form with it.

```
this.addComponent = function() {
      url = CRM.url('civicrm\/a\/#/trialadmin/Component');
      console.log(url)
      // actual url is https://www.sportingdetectiondogs.ca/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/trialadmin/Component?angularDebug=1
      window.location.href = url;
      //CRM.loadPage(url);
      CRM.refreshParent
    }
```

So window.location.href will open the new form but not in a popup window.  I'm also not sure how I would return those values then to the original calling form.  CRM.loadPage does not work - I don't get any errors in the console or anywhere else - the window pops up, and nothing populates in it.  Going to the url manually absolutely works (just not returning - not sure how?).

Thanks again for helping this learning Angular developer.